# SQL Server, backup file - does it exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, database-backups

I am currently doing a project in backing-up SQL Server database. My question is how can I find whether the specified `.bak` file is present in the **DEFAULT BACKUP FOLDER** or not.

Till now what I have learnt is to check whether a file is present or not, I can find that out using:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'D:\Backup\dbbackup.bak'`
```

I also found out that, `RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'FileName'`, but it returns a message, the thing is I want a value in table as result, so that I can access it via java's ResultSet.

But the issue for me is how can I find whether the file is present are not, without giving the file path, but only giving the file name, assuming the file is located in **DEFAULT BACKUP FOLDER**

Also, can I know how to check the integrity of that backup file?

Comment: Word of caution: you are **aware** that those backup files are created **on the machine** where SQL Server is running? So if that's a remote server and you're backing up to the `D:\backup` folder - that's the `D:\backup` folder **on the server** - not on your local machine - just to be clear

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that